# Breeze $filter projections

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, breeze

I am having an issue trying to filter data because breeze is adding the $filter clause at the end of the URL and the WCF\odata service is throwing filter cannot be after select clause.

```
 public IQueryable<order> Orders()
{
    string owner= Membership.GetUser(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name).owner;

    IQueryable<Consigne> q = this.db.Consignes
        //                 .AddQueryOption("Dest", dest)
         .Where(x => x.Owner == owner)

         .Select(f => new order{ Name= f.Name, Address1 = f.Address1, Address2 = f.Address2, Address3 = f.Address3 });
    return q;
}
```

I'm already limiting the result set with the server side Where clause and limiting the fields with the Select projection. If I remove these and let breeze have full control of Where\Select then I blow my security model allowing the js code to have control.

I realize this isn't truly a Breeze issue and more of an odata issue but how are others dealing with this? 
Do you just give up on iQueryable and just create a webapi and pass back json? 
If so, then i'm reinventing the wheel since i also need to deal with skip\take and orderby.

Appreciate the suggestions :)
Kind Regards,
Mike

---

Solved

I've found there is no way for WCF to pass as iQueryable without loosing the TotalCount. WCF is returning a QueryOperationResponse which I can pass back to breeze, but once cast to an object by breeze there is no way I've found in Breeze's QueryHelper.WrapResults to cast the dynamic type back to a usable object to retrieve the extended TotalCount properties.

QueryHelper will execute the query

```
queryResult = Enumerable.ToList((dynamic)queryResult)
```

but

```
request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_InlineCount", out tmp)
```

fails because of the wrong underlying object.

My solution was to Execute the query in my BreezeController and wrap the rows and TotalCount in an array as Breeze would have. Then I can pass the array back as type QueryResult and breeze will serialize to JSON to the client.

```
  public QueryResult Consignees(string filter, int skip, int take)
  {
    WcfService.Context context = new WcfService.Context(new System.Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URI"]));

    //Main Table
    System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<WcfService.Consigne> qMain = context.Consignes.IncludeTotalCount();

    //Projected Table
    System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<Consigne> qProj = (System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<Consigne>)qMain
          .Where(x => x.Refname.StartsWith(filter))
          .Skip(skip)
          .Take(take)
          .Select(f => new Consigne { Refname = f.Refname, Consignee = f.Consignee, Address1 = f.Address1, Address2 = f.Address2, Address3 = f.Address3 });

    System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse<Consigne> qResult= qProj.Execute() as System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse<Consigne>;

    QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult() { Results = qResult.ToList(), InlineCount = qResult.TotalCount };
    return queryResult;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround! You may still be able to use the breeze OData query support by decorating your `Consignees` method with either `[Queryable]` or `[BreezeQueryable]`. You can then ask the Web API to pass you the parsed query parameters by listing `ODataQueryOptions<Consigne> options` in your `Consignees` method signature. Then you don't have to provide your own {filter, take, skip} parameters. You might even be able to use its LINQ expression directly. It's kind of nice :)

Comment: I would love to give control back to breeze, but I still fear that even if did the query would fail since all the predicates are going to be after the select and probably fail due to the projection. I would love to take breeze's filter and orderby clauses and pass them back through the webapi and inject them in the controller instead of the linq .where().  Currently i'm passing back a Refname string not "$filter refname eq xxxx" clause.  I don't believe that linq allows to break it's chaining and inject a string, but that is my next direction for total control and flexability. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 5):

You have some success by passing your filter criteria as simple parameters using the Breeze `.withParameters({...})` clause. You can still use `orderBy`, `take`, `skip`.

### Breeze, DTOs and the Web API

Do you need to use WCF OData? Could you switch to Web API where you have more flexibility?

Suppose we reimagine your example in the Northwind world of DocCode. For convenience, you define a DTO class

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

This is not needed, strictly speaking. But you created this class so you don't ever have to see the ugly anonymous-type-name that is generated for your projection.

Then you add a query method to the `NorthwindController` like this one:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable ProductDtos()
{
    return _repository.Products
        // TODO: move the following into the repository where it belongs
        .Where(x => x.CategoryID == 1) // a surrogate for your 'Owner' filter
        .Select(x => new ProductDto
            {
                ProductID = x.ProductID, 
                ProductName = x.ProductName
            });
}
```

When your client issues a breeze query such as

```
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductDtos')
      .where('ProductName', 'startsWith', 'C')
      .orderBy('ProductName')
      .take(5);
// execute it
```

it resolves to the following URL

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/ProductDtos?$filter=startswith(ProductName,'C') eq true&$orderby=ProductName&$top=5
```

and returns four {ProductID, ProductName} objects.

If you describe `ProductDto` in client-side metadata, breeze will treat these objects as entities and cache them. You'll get change notification, change tracking, validation, etc. You can save the changes back to the server where, in the `beforeSaveEntities` method, you can validate them and convert them back into `Product` entities so that EF can save them to the database. I'm not going into details in this answer but I want you to know that you can do it.

#### Restricted filtering

Note that you **can only filter by the projected properties**, not by properties in the undisclosed root type. For example, the following query fails because `Product.SupplierID` is not among the selected `ProductDto` properties:

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/ProductDtos?$filter=SupplierID eq 18&$orderby=ProductName&$top=5
```

The response is

> Message: "The query specified in the URI is not valid.",
> ExceptionMessage: "Type 'Northwind.Models.ProductDto' does not have a property 'SupplierID'.",

Given your security concerns about undisclosed properties, I assume **you would want this query to fail**.

But if you actually need to filter by some criteria that are not in the projected type, you could change the server method to accept a parameter. For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable ProductDtos(int? supplierID=null)
{
     // TODO: move the following into the repository where it belongs
    var query = _repository.Products
        .Where(x => x.CategoryID == 1); // a surrogate for a security filter

    if (supplierID != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.SupplierID == supplierID);
    }

    return query.Select(x => new ProductDto
            {
                ProductID = x.ProductID, 
                ProductName = x.ProductName
            });
}
```

Now the client can write:

```
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductDtos')
      .withParameters( {supplierID: 18} ) // <-- passed as arg to the GET method
      .where('ProductName', 'startsWith', 'C')
      .orderBy('ProductName')
      .take(5);
// execute it
```

which resolves to

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/ProductDtos?$filter=startswith(ProductName,'C') eq true&$orderby=ProductName&$top=5&supplierID=18
```

and the result is two `ProductDto` objects that pass all filter criteria.

p.s.: I'm not making this up. I tried this code and got these results exactly as described in this answer.

Comment: Wow! Ward thanks a million!
I've been struggling to parse and the URI on the server so I could shift the $filter to before the $select on the fly but your solution seems much more elegant.
Breeze is an amazing technology and I'm still wrapping my head around all its possibilities, thank you for your suggestions and all your hard work. I am going to follow your examples above and redesign accordingly, I’ll let you know how I make out.
Regards,
Mike Pisano

Comment: Regarding Need for WCF Odata, it’s just where I ended up after multiple test applications trying to decide between WCF\ODATA\RIA while I was looking at Lightswitch HTML, MVC and other technologies prior to going the SPA route. This is a brand new application and I have no prerequisites except EF.

Comment: Ward, I have it working but now I’m struggling because seems WebApi’s JSON shape doesn’t permit $inlinecount=allpages responce even though I’ve added IncludeTotalCount() to the query. Seems like I have to implement PageSize attributes from what I’m reading, any insight?

Comment: Dead End so far, I implemented PageSize attributes, but is seems breeze doesn't like the JSON presumed since its now wrapped in $type":"System.Web.Http.OData.PageResult`1. Going to scour the web tonight and see what webapi hacks i can find.

Comment: I'm confused. All you should need to do on the Breeze side is add `.inlineCount()` to your query. See the queryTests.js in DocCode. What the heck is "includeTotalCount()"?

Comment: Having breeze inlinecount was returning my take amount, not the true inline count

IncludeTotalCount goes on the linq query along with with skip  & take args from breeze and my select projection.

If your saying that the inlinecount from breeze should work then I will reexamine it again, maybe I missed something

Comment: Ward, I'm double checked and I am correct, I can see two database queries firing and in the EF logs both the count and the query both have "top x" in the SQL. I will dig deeper in the morning - regards Mike

Comment: One other thing that might be relevance is my project isn't directly consuming the EF layer. It attaches back to another wcf service where the databases are located. It's only a thin wrapper, no logic and I see the correct inline count comming back in the XML as long as I IncludeTotalCount in the call, putting in the js still only gets me take. Right now I'm not even using the js code, just calling the breeze service directly from chrome, it then calls the main server gets all the columns does the projection and returns the limited set. I'm going to debug into the breeze attribute handlers .

Comment: Breeze is not seeing the MS_InlineCount in QueryHelper. I ran wire shark and I can see the limited projection comming back from the data server with <m:count>5567</m:count> . The whole thing is bizarre, why do I have this feeling that this is gonna be one of those really stupid answers that I overlooked.... I'm going to clear my head and re-approach

Comment: Still digging into it, but seems  wcf is returning  QueryOperationResponse that has the correct TotalCount as queryResponse, casting the object seems to be tricky considering its base class, will post more of my saga tomorrow

Comment: If I understand, you're saying that the breeze inlineCount is ignored by your service whereas it understands includeTotalCount. But then you have the challenge of returning the count to the client such that Breeze can pick it up. If so ... big "if" ... the solution for you may be simple: a custom JsonResultsAdapter. In brief, grab the Web API adapter and override the `extractResults` method with something that moves your total count value into the expected inlineCount slot.

Comment: You can also tweek the AjaxAdapter to replace the `$inlineCount` on the outgoing URL to your `TotalCount`. That way, you can write your application code with `.inlineCount()` as if that worked and the adapter will produce the proper URL automagically.  HTH

Comment: I got it working, I've found there is no way for WCF to pass as iQueryable without loosing the TotalCount. WCF is returning a QueryOperationResponse which I can pass back to breeze for query, but once cast to an object by breeze there is no way I've found in QueryHelper.WrapResults to cast the dynamic type back to a usable object to retrieve the extended TotalCount properties. My solution was to Execute the query in my BreezeController and wrap the rows and TotalCount in an array as Breeze would have. Then I can pass the array back as type QueryResult and breeze will serialize to JSON.

Comment: Solved, Example Code block added to initial post at top

Comment: Now that I'm over paging, I'm having so trouble putting the DTO entity back through the BreezeController. Appreciate any insight on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092009/breeze-webapi-update-projections