# Breeze Webapi Update Projections

Tags: wcf-data-services, breeze

Continuing on after my initial WebApi Filtering and paging a projection Dilemma

[Breeze $filter projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880992/breeze-filter-projections) thread

I am now trying to update my backend database with little success.

Giving the Fact that I am:

```
    public IQueryable<ConsigneDTO> Consignees(string refname)
    {
        IQueryable<ConsigneDTO> q = this.db.Consignes
             .Where(x => x.Refname == refname)
                  .Select(f => new ConsigneDTO {Refname = f.Refname, Consignee = f.Consignee, Address1 = f.Address1, Address2 = f.Address2, Address3 = f.Address3});
        return q;
    }
```

Whats the easiest way to put this data back from Breeze?

I see my changed data coming back in both overrides

```
    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
    }

    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
    }
```

But no easy way to push these into the underlying context which is a WCF service stemming from Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.

How do I call

```
  Context.UpdateChanges(EntityInfo);
```

or

```
  Context.UpdateChanges(SaveMap);
```

Especially Considering EntityInfo and SaveMap contains DTO?

Must I completely ignore the SaveChanges() mechanism and do my own CRUD calls? I don't even see any good non-breeze examples on updating projections, which make me feel this is deep rooted.

As explained in prior thread, I can change most things about this project. The only issues I have are the databases are on another server and has columns that cannot be public and my only way at the tables are EF5.

I've chosen to wrap EF thinly using OData-v3 / WCF-Data-Services and access them from my breeze controller on the web server.

So far reading\querying\filtering and paging are all working great on SPA, but with only the R of "C_UD", I'm more then willing to rework this project.

Kind Regards
Mike

Comment: I am going to try to be level with you - You say that you have a WCF service you are getting data from - what are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to post data back to a GET method?  I hope not...  If you are trying to perform a data save into a WCF service, do you have an UPDATE or POST method?  Have you tried to intercept the save and use those methods?  If you are using a WCF service and want Breeze to be able to override your GET method by POSTing data, then I feel you need to do a bit more research into WCF services.  Please understand I have nothing to do with the Breeze team...

Comment: @PWKad Appreciate the Effort :)  I am familiar with WCF (but always learning) and I can R\W my data server from my controller with a .Select(); q.Address3="foo"; Context.UpdateObject(q); Context.SaveChanges; My issue is more Breeze Related. Breeze returns me EntityInfo class in the BeforeSaveEntity or a SaveMap and SaveBundle in other overrides. None of these seem to be able to pass to UpdateObject() and even if I could, It's a DTO because of the Select() projection and I don't think WCF will know what to do with it. I'm going to remove the projection as a test and get over the breeze hurdle.

Comment: I've updated the initial question to point more at Breeze Overrides and the DTO - Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

The Breeze EntityManager.saveChanges call is intended to save changes to entities that were previously queried.  This process can be automated by Breeze because it has metadata regarding these entity types and is able to construct the appropriate code on the server to persist them. In your case what you are returning from your queries are not 'entities' and unless you can turn them into entities Breeze will not be able to persist them. So you have several approaches that you can try.

The first is to take your DTO's when retrieved on the client and dynamically construct "partial" entities from them that can later be fully resolved if any changes need to be made. See John Papa's [Code Camper](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/code-camper-js-course) sample to see an example of this. As a side note, if your DTO actually includes Breeze entities within the projection then even this is not necessary.

Another approach is to bypass Breeze completely when attempting to save these. Simply use the Breeze ajax adapter directly and post your data directly to whatever endpoint you'd like.  Obviously, in this case, you will need to write all of the server side code necessary to persist the posted data.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I assume they are entities but "DTO entities", savemap looks good and the entityInfo in BeforeSaveEntity does show EntityState as Modified and is tracking OriginalValuesMap for the changed properties.  Everything looks complete, except a means to cast it back to the original table
I have been using the CodeCamper and TempHire projects as a template; I think my underlying difference is that my projection is server side in the Controller, not .js in the client. We can’t take allow Breese to project for security, so we resorted to WebApi over true Odata. Appreciate any other help :)